# How to create a JSON object with duplicate keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm working on a SailsJS project and I need to create a json object for my ORM search to work, This is how the search should be performed

```
Venue.find({
            is_published: true,
            restaurant_services: {
                contains: '"delivery":"1"',
                contains: '"takeout":"1"'
            },
            restaurant_specialties: {
                contains: '"breakfast":"1"',
            }
        }).exec
```

So as you may see the JSON object inside the Find() is the one O need to create and the values inside has duplicate keys.

Comment: Shouldn't the `contains` key be an Object if you want that format?

Comment: That is not JSON.  That is a javascript object literal.  JSON is simply a seriliazation format. What you are dealing with is a fundamental javascript issue arround have two properties with the same name.  Have you considered changing your data structure to something like `restaurant_services: { contains: ['"delivery":"1"', '"takeout":"1"'] }`

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Your should try using something like this instead:

```
Venue.find({
            is_published: true,
            restaurant_services: {
                contains:  ['"delivery":"1"','"takeout":"1"']
            },
            restaurant_specialties: {
                contains: [ '"breakfast":"1"' ]
            }
        }).exec
```

Or this:

```
Venue.find({
            is_published: true,
            restaurant_services: {
                contains: {"delivery":"1","takeout":"1"}
            },
            restaurant_specialties: {
                contains: { "breakfast":"1" }
            }
        }).exec
```

Comment: It should be `contains: ['"delivery":"1"','"takeout":"1"']`, since that's an array, not an object. Unless, of course, the `'` are taken off.

Comment: That was my first thought. Then, I thought why not making it an object? But you are right, with the `'`, it should be an array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the {... } Jason represents a map and therefore can't have duplicate keys.  Although duplicate keys are strictly not Syntax errors but they are going to able also not going to work as expected with browsers or json  libraries.  If you can't change the syntax for your json object then you will have to produce that json by string concatenation  instead of the normal Javascript type approach.